# No breadcrumb in meeting workspace

Tags: breadcrumb, meeting-workspace

I created a meeting workspace in Sharepoint 2010 and it doesn't show the full breadcrumb path. I went to the site settings Navigation tab and made sure it is inheriting navigation from the parent but it is still not showing the full breadcrumb path.

Any idea how this can be resolved without having to manually edit the page?

Comment: Sorry, @dkong ... I doesn't look like you finished your question?